# getting count values in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a `table` with 3 `columns` and looks like

```
branchid  semesterid  courseid
 4          25           2        
 4          36           5
 4          23           3
 4          12           10 
 4          34           15
 4          2            7
 4          23           42

 7          23           9
 7          10           6
 7          34           3
 7          20           17
```

I need the count of semesterid and courseid of that branch

```
SELECT branchid, count(semesterid), count(courseid) WHERE branchid = 4
```

When I execute this query, the count(semesterid) shows wrong count and courseid shows correct count of 7

Comment: what is the value semesterid shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my crystal ball I predict you need this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT semesterid), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT courseid) 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE branchid = 4;
```

... as the query shown should work just fine for counting the number of records (but not unique records).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT branchid, 
       count(distinct semesterid) as semesterid, 
       count(distinct courseid) as courseid
FROM   <table>
WHERE  branchid = 4
group by branchid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of unique results you have to replace *count(id)* with *count(distinct id)*